# How to fix the "the-default-package-is-not-permitted-by-the-import-package-syntax" error while using geojson library?

Tags: java, maven, osgi, geojson

I was upgrading to new library of geojson from version 14.2 to 20.2. And I was keep of getting below maven build error which is failing at the bundle processing with the message "the-default-package . -is-not-permitted-by-the-import-package-syntax".

I expect the maven build with bundle processing to be successful but the actual output is "the-default-package-is-not-permitted-by-the-import-package-syntax" error.

Answer (score 0):

While upgrading the geotools library from old version 14.2 to new version 20.2, there were lot of changes has been made.

[GeoTools Upgrade](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/welcome/upgrade.html)

This was one of the link that would help everyone to do it very easily. But with the upgradation of geotools, we also update the gt-geojson library too. This library contains the class "Skunkwork" without any package name which result in above error during bundle processing of maven build. To avoid this error,i have to remove this class. And it works fine.

**Before Fix**

[image: Geojson jar contains a class "Skunkwork" with no package name]

POM Configuration:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geojson</artifactId>
        <version>20.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**After Fix**

[image: Geojson jar contains no default package class]

POM Configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-geojson</artifactId>
    <version>20.2-fixed</version>
</dependency>
```

**Note:** This jar needs to be manually installed to your local repository. And as well as you need to install the fixed jar to remote artifactory if used by your code base such as Nexus, JFrog etc.